# How to share photo using facebook like or share button

Tags: php, facebook

I am using this facebook share link

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=458358780877780&
link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
caption=Reference%20Documentation&
description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/
```

what it does is sharing link with the name, caption and descrption.

What I want is to share a photo. (same output when I directly go to facebook -> click photo -> then post it)

Is this thing possible or already available?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to `post` a picture this way. The `picture` parameter is meant to welcome a customized link picture.

If you want to post a picture to a timeline, you have three options:

1. **Uploading a photo to the app’s album**: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ (scenario 1).
2. **Creating a New Album and Adding a Photo**: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ (scenario 2). 
   Because you want to upload the photo from a URL and not from your computer, here is the line you'll need: `$image_url = '@' . realpath("http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg");`.  Then, just use that `$image_url` in your dialog URL.
3. **User-generated photos**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/.

Comment: I'm going to use the option #2.
the problem I encountered is how to use $image_url = '@' . realpath("http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg"); thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>  <----- click photo -> then post it
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```